# Why express validator oneOf is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm building a project in NodeJS and I'm also using Express. To validate my requests from the client I'm using Express validator and the methods check, oneOf, body, and etc. 
I built my PUT endpoint and in parallel also I implemented a validation for the fields to update using `oneOf`. My goal is that when a client tries to update should at least change one of the fields otherwise a message should come ups informing the client nothing was updated. 
My issue is that the PUT updates ignoring my check I implemented and cannot understand the issue as I already did similar before and was working perfectly.

My validator for update looks like:

```
const updateBookRules = [
    oneOf([
        check("title")
            .exists()
            .withMessage("Title is required"),
        check("category")
            .exists()
            .withMessage("Category is required"),
        check("price")
            .isNumeric()
            .withMessage("Price should be a number"),
        check("img")
            .exists()
            .withMessage("Img is required"),
        sanitizeBody("price").toFloat()
    ])
];
```

In the route, I'm calling this validation as:

```
// PUT Update a book
router.put("/:asin", check.updateBook, check.rules, async (req, res) => {
    // Request ID
    const asin = req.params.asin;
    // Await the book
    await book
        // Call model to update the product
        .updateBook(asin, req.body)
        // Response a message
        .then(book =>
            res.json({
                message: `The book #${asin} has been updated`,
                content: book
            })
        )
        // Errors if any
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.status) {
                res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message });
            }
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
        });
});
```

The strange is the validation is ignored and I can put also empty strings and no error happens I don't know what is my mistake.

Please comment if you would like to see something more and I will update the question.

Comment: It would help if you linked to the library in question...

Comment: The library is Express-validator https://express-validator.github.io/docs/
I mentioned it in my post

Comment: @Jakub your `updateBookRules` can not be an array. I do it in this way: `function updateBookRules () { return check() }`

Answer (score 0):

*Edited Answer*

I think I may know the issue. Your code seems fine now that I've had access to the whole repo, but you definitely need to be bringing in `validationResult` in order to check for validation errors, then stop execution of the router middleware. So, the `router.put` route-handler would start with:

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

// PUT Update a book
router.put("/:asin", check.updateBook, check.rules, async (req, res) => {

    // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
```

I'm still not sure about how you setup updateBookRules to use the `sanitizeBody()` call, and how you have it wrapped in an array. If the above still doesn't work after adding `validationResult`, try this:

```
const updateBookRules = oneOf([
        check("title")
            .exists()
            .withMessage("Title is required"),
        check("category")
            .exists()
            .withMessage("Category is required"),
        check("price")
            .isNumeric()
            .withMessage("Price should be a number"),
        check("img")
            .exists()
            .withMessage("Img is required"),    
]);
```

Then make the route-handler signature:

```
router.put("/:asin", sanitizeBody("price").toFloat(), check.updateBook, check.rules, async (req, res) => {
```

Also, are you sure there is an error? The [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#oneofvalidationchains-message) state that oneOf :

> Creates a middleware instance that will ensure at least one of the
>   given chains passes the validation.

You are checking to make sure that these different fields exist at the PUT route. As long as one of them does exist, `check.updateBook` will pass. You aren't checking for *change* here, so the user can simply send you back the same book information, and nothing will fail right?

Per your comments, if you really don't want to use the `validationResult` you can try to run the validations imperatively, check out the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/running-imperatively.html)

Comment: The require i have it i just posted part of the files but I can share my repo for a better look. I would like to have it that I call the Middleware to make the checks and do the put. I did similar for the post and was working

Comment: @Jakub Sure, post a link to the repo and I will fork it and mess around.

Comment: I tried as you suggest before but I have the same result in nothing change I also so other epos online where people used a similar approach but seem I'm missing something

Comment: @Jakub See if my updated answer does the trick. I read through the express-validator docs and your code in the repo and I think that should work.

Comment: But is not what I want to achieve as I want a middleware and in my post, I have `check.createBook` and works without a problem and I'm validated with the second part `check.rules` without the need to import the validator in the routes but only in the middleware. My question is why for the post can be done and put no?
I also used the same way in another project and was working actually. 
herehttps://github.com/Jakub41/MarketplaceAPI-like-Amazon/blob/master/src/routes/products/products.route.js#L68

Comment: It is middleware. It runs, and then if there are errors you find them with the validationResult. The docs seem to state that this is the way to use them, have you tried the above example? Also, I'm not sure that your validation is failing. The docs state that oneOf just ensures that one of the validations passes. So, as long as any one of those fields exists, this validation passes. These validations do nothing to check changes.

Comment: The problem is as you suggest is not use the Middleware as check.rules should do what you wrote 
https://github.com/Jakub41/BooksAPI/blob/master/src/middleware/validator.middleware.js
also, I followed this guide:
https://dev.to/nedsoft/a-clean-approach-to-using-express-validator-8go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204470/discussion-between-daniel-schroeder-and-jakub).